# Solution Verification for a Poisson processes question

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Suppose that the number of customers arriving at a fast-food
> restaurant on a given day follows $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Assume
> that each customer purchases a drink with probability $p$,
> independently from other customers. Let $X$ be the number of customers
> who purchase drinks. Let $Y$ be the number of customers that do not
> purchase drinks. Find $\text{E}[X^2Y^2]$

My attempt:

Here, the original Poisson process has been split into two Poisson processes, such that $X\text{~Poisson}(\lambda p)$ and $Y\text{~Poisson}(\lambda q)$. Also, since when a Poisson process is split, two independent Poisson processes are created, hence $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

So, $\text{E}[X^2Y^2]=\text{E}[X^2]\text{E}[Y^2]=(\lambda p+\lambda^2p^2)\cdot(\lambda q+ \lambda^2q^2)=\lambda^2pq\cdot(\lambda^2pq+2\lambda)$

but the correct answer is $\lambda^2pq(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)$. So, what did i do wrong?

Comment: $(\lambda p+\lambda^2p^2)\cdot(\lambda q+ \lambda^2q^2)=\lambda^2pq(1+\lambda p)(1+\lambda q)=\lambda^2pq(\lambda^2 pq+\lambda+1)$
so there is a small issue in your computations. Also how do you know the correct answer?

Comment: lol. I made a mistake in reading the answer.$\lambda^2pq(\lambda^2 pq+\lambda+1)
$ is the correct answer

Comment: Well, looks like you got the correct answer then. ;)